# How to texture a floor so that edges have slightly different texture than the rest of the floor

Tags: textures, unreal-4, uv-mapping, materials

When trying to create somewhat realistic environments, I often find that the edges where floor/wall/ceiling meet will have slightly different texture compared to the rest of the floor/wall/ceiling.

An example of this can be seen on this concrete walkway:
[image: Image of concrete floor]
The parts of the concrete away from any walls is worn smooth by people walking across it, but it becomes lighter and rougher closer to the wall or the metal pole.

What are some techniques (general or UE4 specific) to emulate this when texturing a level?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tileable nine slices. These are textures that have 3 parts, corners, edges and a center.

[image]

(This is a scaled one, but you get the point)

So, first of all, get or create a texture that has a tileable middle and edges. Split it into 9 parts (they don't need to be equal in size), then tile the center both horizontally and vertically, the edges should tiled paralell to their direction and the corners shouldn't be tiled.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see how this would work, the only situation that this can apply to is a closed room with exactly 4 sides. Even just having a single door would break this, or any turns, curved sides, basically any room that is not a closed box with 4 complete walls.

Comment: @Hand you could extend it. You only need to add 4 new corners for the 270° turns. If the rooms are irregular (don't have right angles) then I'm out of ideas.